# ReSharper + NUnit tests show inconclusive when testing inheritance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Using Resharper Ultimate 10 and NUnit 3
Trying to write some unit tests that have a base class

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTests
{
    protected BaseTests( /*some parameters */)
    {
        // some ctor code
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // some setup code
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // some tests code
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        // some tests code
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestA : BaseTests
{
    public TestA() : base(/* some parameters */) { }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestB : BaseTests
{
    public TestB() : base(/* some parameters */) { }
}
```

My problem is that the unit test runner (resharper)
shows those tests `inconclusive` eventhough none of the tests fail when I debug.

Ideas?

Comment: Is this working for you now? As of ReSharper 10.0.2 and NUnit 3.0.1, we are still unable to run _inherited_ tests in either VS 2013 or 2015. Curious if you've had better luck than me!

Comment: I actually did succeed in running those tests with RS and VS15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunit 3 RTM isn't supported just yet. The current release of ReSharper 10.0.1 only supports Nunit 3 Beta 5. ReSharper 10.0.2 will have support, it's due in the next few weeks. I don't know if the [current EAP](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/11/24/resharper-ultimate-10-0-2-eap/) has added RTM support yet, but it might be worth giving it a try.